# Completely overwrite text file with StreamWriter

Tags: vb.net, file, filestream, streamwriter, overwrite

I am trying to add a simple toggle to my program which among other things writes to a file. The file contains nothing besides one line of text which I want to either read "on" or "off".

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click

    Dim fStrm As FileStream = File.Open(muteFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    Dim strmWrtr As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fStrm)
    strmWrtr.Flush()

    If PictureBox2.Tag = "On" Then
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.SoundOff
        PictureBox2.Tag = "Off"
        strmWrtr.Write("off", False)
    Else
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.SoundOn
        PictureBox2.Tag = "On"
        strmWrtr.Write("on", False)
    End If

    strmWrtr.Close()
    fStrm.Close()

End Sub
```

Everything works, but it behaves differently than I expected it to. Writing "off" to the file works fine, but when I use `strmWrtr.Write("on," False)` the file contains "onf" as if it just overwrote character by character and left what it didn't overwrite. Furthermore, if I change it from "on" and "off" to "123456789" and "off" I am left with "off456789".

The behavior I would like is to completely overwrite the file.

One solution I thought of is to always delete and recreate the file, but I was hoping there is a cleaner way to accomplish this, perhaps I'm just missing something.

Comment: You are specifically using `OpenOrCreate`. If you want to overwrite the file each time, use `Create`. Better yet, don't bother with explicit streams (you are not using `Using` like you should anyway), and simply do `File.WriteAllText(muteFile, "on")`.

Comment: @GSerg Switching to `Create` indeed fixed it, thank you. Also, I attempted the `File.WriteAllText` method (written exactly as you did) and did not further the endeavor due to: `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.String]'.'` which I don't understand as every example I see looks exactly the same as my code - I'm not too worried about it since my problem is fixed now, but I can post another question if you feel the community would benefit from it.

Comment: @TylerN Perhaps IntelliSense accidentally made you use `File.WriteAllLines` instead of `File.WriteAllText`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton You are correct. It's great to have multiple sets of eyes and minds.

Comment: @GSerg Since my problem was solved I would like to mark it as answered for potential future community users, would you like to do the honors? Credit where credit is due. Otherwise I don't mind answering it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifically using [`FileMode.OpenOrCreate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.8) which means "reuse if exists".
If you want to overwrite the file each time, use `FileMode.Create`.

Better yet, don't bother with explicit streams (you are not using [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) like you should anyway), and simply do `File.WriteAllText(muteFile, "on")`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just using a StreamWriter with append set to False. This will overwrite the file every time. Also, I'm only writing to the file inside the using block here. I'm not doing other operations while the file is open.

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    If PictureBox2.Tag = "On" Then
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.SoundOff
        PictureBox2.Tag = "Off"
    Else
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.SoundOn
        PictureBox2.Tag = "On"
    End If

    Using strmWrtr = New StreamWriter(muteFile, False)
        strmWrtr.Write(PictureBox2.Tag, False)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that while I was already setting the append argument to `False` in my original code, the fact that I was opening the file with a FileStream in `OpenOrCreate` mode was causing the behavior I noticed. Otherwise, if the code is written how @HackSlash has above (completely avoiding FileStream), setting append to `False` will make it correctly overwrite.